# Visual Studio 2017 Report using a Matrix

Tags: matrix, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have built a report with multiple datasets from SQL and multiple matrices. The report shows current ytd data per month. The problem is that in the preview, the matrix shows all the future months with lots of zeros or null values. Is there any way make columns invisible if the data contains nulls or zeros? or perhaps based on a date that the report goes out? I have been researching how to fix this on SQL side but with no luck. Someone advised that I rather fix it in the presentation layer, but this is the first time I am using Visual Studio so my knowledge is extremely limited.